# DNS flush, nor clearing cache does not work

Tags: caching, dns

I recently changed hosting providers. propagation has just completed. everyone can access the site except me. BUT when i change the network, from WIFI to 4G, it works. When i change back, it shows stuff from old hosting provider. Why?

Comment: This is really off topic here, but since I'm here... Propagation across the authoritative DNS servers doesn't mean all the worlds DNS servers / DNS caches have the revision. They won't under the TTL expires and they have to reload their cache. This will happen at different times after the update for all DNS servers.

Comment: so its gonna be updated it just takes time?

Comment: Yes, assuming there is nothing else wrong, which obviously no one can really know, then it will work, eventually. It can take up to whatever the TTL was before your update. If after that time it is still a problem then you need to investigate further. However I imagine it will be fine because clearly at least some DNS servers / caches have got the update.

Comment: Next time, if you need the update to be recognised quickly, lower the TTL in advance.. do the change.. and then raise it when everything is definitely OK. If it's an emergency change you didn't know about in advance then there's nothing you can do about it really other than wait after you do the changes.

Comment: ok thx!! nice  this is clever